# Python json.loads() returning a string and not the dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have a following simple code. The type of datajson I'm getting is String. Want to receive it as a json.

```
import json
datajson = '''"{'name' : '24', 'phone':12345678, address{'street':'abc','suburb':45}}"'''
info = json.loads(datajson)
print(type(info))
print(info)
```

Comment: please make sure to use 3 ` to start a code block

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to load the json by using json.loads().
I have noticed that your input is incorrect.

Here is the working code.

```
    import json 
    datajson = '''{"name" : "24", "phone":12345678, "address":{"street":"abc","suburb":45}}'''
    info = json.loads(datajson) 
    print(type(info)) 
    print(info)
```

Output:
<class 'dict'>

{'name': '24', 'phone': 12345678, 'address': {'street': 'abc', 'suburb': 45}}